# How to set image background to div using css

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason the image background is not showing up on my div.

css:

```
.loading-on {
    background-image: url('./assets/images/app-loader-on.png');
}
```

html:

```
<div className={`loading loading-on`}></div>
```

The image is not loading, while when I inspect element the div has src as url('/app-loader-on.8e87a389.png'), so some hashing is being added.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-article",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel src/index.html -p 8000",
    "build-user": "yarn --cwd '../../packages/user' build-npm",
    "build": "yarn build-user && yarn clean && yarn install && parcel build src/index.html --no-cache && cp src/xd_receiver.html ./dist && cp src/ads.txt ./dist",
    "clean": "rm -rf .cache dist node_modules"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5"
  }
}
```

Does it mean only image would appear after building the app, how about development mode?

Comment: try another options for image, size and repeat: `background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:contain;
   height:200px;width:1200px;`

Comment: thank you working!

Comment: add it as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try another options for image, size and repeat:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-size:contain; 
height:200px;width:1200px;
```